what to choose i here help me
I have 2 VPSs. In my first VPS I run node successfully. In my second VPS when I run node, it says.
Restarting services...
Daemons using outdated libraries
--------------------------------
  1. dbus.service                 5. ssh.service                  9. user@0.service
  2. getty@tty1.service           6. systemd-logind.service       10. none of the above
  3. networkd-dispatcher.service  7. systemd-manager
  4. qemu-guest-agent.service     8. unattended-upgrades.service

(Enter the items or ranges you want to select, separated by spaces.)

Which services should be restarted?

I don't think any of these services depend on node, or that any damage will occur from restarting them. So the answer would be 10.
